# Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation

Tags: javascript, java, android

I got an error when js invoke Android's native method on android 5,6,7

```
Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
```

From javascript I am calling native android's method like this:

```
Android.setIsGoBack(true);
```

and on android side I have this method in abstract class like:

```
@JavascriptInterface
override fun setIsGoBack(isGoBack: Boolean) {
     (activity as DashBoardActivity).isGoBack = isGoBack
     (activity as DashBoardActivity).setHeader("")
}
```

and I am not sure what is actually getting wrong on Android 5,6,7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the above issue. The problem was I was calling the method from javascript and updating UI `(activity as DashBoardActivity).setHeader("")` in some other thread than UI. So changed my method to:

```
 @JavascriptInterface
    override fun setIsGoBack(isGoBack: Boolean) {


        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            (activity as DashBoardActivity).isGoBack = isGoBack
            (activity as DashBoardActivity).setHeader("")
        }
    }
```

updating UI on main thread worked for me.